# modify unique_together constraint to save new object and delete old

Tags: django

I have a model with a unique_together constraint on four fields.  Instead of raising the normal Validation Error, however, I want to delete the old object and replace it with the newer one (or maybe update the old one?  would also work).  I'm a little at a loss as to how to go about doing this, or if there's maybe a better way to go about achieving this behavior.

EDIT:

Any downside to modifying the save method to just check the database for an instance with those four fields and deleting it if I find one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overriding the `save` method is OK, but it will fetch the database every time, possibly causing performance loss. It will be better, and more *pythonic*, if you handle the `ValidationError`:

```
try:
   YourModel.objects.create(
       unique_together_field_1, 
       unique_together_field_2,
       unique_together_field_3,
       unique_together_field_4,
       ...
   )
except YourModel.ValidationError:
   # update or replace the existing model
```

**EDIT**

You can use this code in the model's manager:

```
class YourModelManager(models.Manager):
    def create(**kwargs):
        try:
            super(YourModelManager, self).create(**kwargs)
        except YourModel.ValidationError:
            # handle here the error
            # kwargs is a dictionary with the model fields
```

and in the model:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    unique_together_field_1 = ....
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [...]

    objects = YourModelManager()
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/) about custom managers.

Comment: This would go on the model itself?

Comment: No, wherever you create your model: in a `view` for example

Comment: Gotcha--I'm a little nervous about that as that means if we create the instance in various places, someone would need to remember to include that code each time.

Comment: that is true. You can create a utility class with this logic, or you can override the create method in the model's manager. Let me update my answer.